# How to get dynamically subset of data frame by list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

#### My intend

I like to filter a data frame dynamically by a `dict` that is holding a `list` of `dicts` with `column` and `value` information to filter on.

Expected result should look like this:

```
result = {'brand': ['Honda','Honda','Toyota'],
              'model': ['a','b','d']
            }
```

#### My data frame

```
cars = {'brand': ['Honda','Honda','Honda','Toyota','Toyota','Audi'],
              'model': ['a','b','c','d','a','b'],
            }
```

#### My dict

Is holding information about relation between cars:

```
relation = {
    'relation1':[
        {'brand':'Honda','model':'a'},
        {'brand':'Honda','model':'b'},
        {'brand':'Toyota','model':'d'}
    ],
    'relation2':[
        {'brand':'...','model':'...'},
        {'brand':'...','model':'...'}
    ]
}
```

#### My try to setup list comprehension

```
' | '.join([f'{repr(k)}=={repr(v)}' for d in relation['relation1'] for k,v in d.items()])
```

#### Issues

1. Implement filter will give an error:

   ```
   KeyError: "brand=='Honda' | model=='a' | brand=='Honda' | model=='b' | brand=='Toyota' | model=='d'"
   ```
2. Adjusting filter to combine the dict values inside with `&` and outside with `|` so filter looks like:

   ```
   (brand=='Honda' & model=='a') | (brand=='Honda' & model=='b') | (brand=='Toyota' & model=='d')
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested list comprehension:

```
q = ' | '.join([f"({' & '.join(f'{k}=={repr(v)}' for k,v in d.items())})" 
                for d in relation['relation1']])
print (q)
(brand=='Honda' & model=='a') | 
(brand=='Honda' & model=='b') | 
(brand=='Toyota' & model=='b')


df = df.query(q)
print (df)
    brand model
0   Honda     a
1   Honda     b
3  Toyota     d
```

Comment: Thanks, deals with both issues, I get the difference to my initial approache and I am able to adapt it.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can simply do a `merge`:

```
print (df_cars.merge(pd.DataFrame(relation["relation1"])))

   brand model
0  Honda     a
1  Honda     b
```

Comment: forest for the trees - in this case it seems to be the "quickest" approache. Hope it is okay accepting jezrael´s answer cause it deals with  using / understandig list comprehension - Upvote for you

Comment: No problem, happy coding.